# Mailchimp export API JSON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Mailchimp's JSON output for the export API is a weird formatted JSON that looks like this:

```
  ["Email Address","First Name","Last Name","Company","FirstOrder","LastOrder","CustomerID","SalesRep","ScreenName","PlayerPage","PlayerPDF","Services Purchased","Contests","EMAIL_TYPE","MEMBER_RATING","OPTIN_TIME","OPTIN_IP","CONFIRM_TIME","CONFIRM_IP","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","GMTOFF","DSTOFF","TIMEZONE","CC","REGION","LAST_CHANGED","LEID","EUID"]
  ["john@domain.com","John","Doe","ACME Inc","2010-09-07","2010-09-07","ABC123","sally","","","","Service1","","html",2,"",null,"2011-12-23 15:58:44","10.0.1.1","34.0257000","-84.1418000","-5","-4","America\/Kentucky\/Monticello","US","GA","2014-04-11 18:38:39","40830325","82c81e14a"]
  ["jane@domain2.com","Jane","Doe","XYZ Inc","2011-05-02","2011-05-02","XYZ001","jack","","","","Service2","","html",2,"",null,"2011-12-23 15:58:44","10.0.1.1","34.0257000","-84.1418000","-5","-4","America\/Kentucky\/Monticello","US","GA","2014-04-11 18:38:40","40205835","6c23329a"]
```

Each record is on a line of it's own with "\n" creating line breaks.

How can I convert it to a normal JSON or do something with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `gibbon` gem, as they've already done the work of adapting the API for you:

https://github.com/amro/gibbon